# Creating a Vite React Project using Yarn Versions 4.0.1 or 4.0.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, yarnpkg

I'm looking to create a Vite React project using Yarn, specifically targeting versions 4.0.1 or 4.0.2. Currently, with the corepack enabled, I'm seeing version 1.22.19 of Yarn available. However, I specifically need to utilize Yarn versions 4.0.1 or 4.0.2 for my project. How can I accomplish this?

Any guidance or steps on how to use Yarn versions 4.0.1 or 4.0.2 to initialize a Vite React project would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't know what this has to do with vite if you just want to upgrade yarn.  There's literally set-by-step instructions to migrate from v1 in their provided documentation https://yarnpkg.com/migration/guide

Answer (score 0):

Following the directions on the [yarn site](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install), I was able to install version 4.0.2 without any problems.

To create a vite react project using the latest version of yarn you have to create the project as you are used to do using

```
yarn create vite my-project --template react
```

and then edit the package.json file by adding

> "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2"

as in the following example:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

and finally running `yarn install` the project should install everything using the specified version and should create a .yarn folder automatically.